# Box.net and Dropbox

Tags: ios, dropbox

I have an iOS app with Dropbox integration. It's possible to download/upload/preview files, navigation and edit some files. Also I need add box.net integration. How much it can take? And how compatible Dropbox and box.net api?

Can anyone compare developing with Dropbox and box.net?

Comment: What does this have to do with MVC?

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox API have different working modes to use it: just upload files as backup, explore the system file, have full access to dropbox, etc.

You can take a look in their web:
https://www.dropbox.com/developers

They have drop ins, which allow you to save to dropbox or load files: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins

Datastore: These days, your app needs to store and sync more than just files. With the Datastore API, structured data like contacts, to-do items, and game state can be synced effortlessly. Datastores support multiple platforms, offline access, and automatic conflict resolution.
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore

Sync API: Work with files on Dropbox through a familiar, file system-like interface. The Sync API takes care of syncing and notifying you of remote changes so your app can respond instantly. It also handles caching, network flakiness, and offline logic so you don't have to.
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync

And Core API, which give you the access to everything in the most low level
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core

About box, they have differents API so they are not compatible. You'll need to manage each thing in different way, but as I can see (I have in mind to implement it too), it works in a similar way to dropbox.

Here you can see all the information: http://developers.box.com/sdks/ and you have a tutorial here: http://developers.box.com/box-ios-sdk-tutorial/
I can't tell you more because I haven't started to implement it.

Comment: Thanks, but what about comparing with Box.net?

Comment: I've just edit the comment, but it's general information, I couldn't implement it yet

Answer (score 0):

For box.net you have a kind of open-source framework which includes viewing, editing and uploading files. It has top-notch security by using the same security the company provides you with their website and Box sync (for example the SMS verification by logging in on a new devices).

[Box developers site](http://developers.box.com)

They also provide a forum where you can ask your questions, also StackOverflow does provide a [box.net](/questions/tagged/box.net) tag under Box API.

I don't have experience with the Dropbox API, but I guess temporarily storing files will help you cross platforming Box and Dropbox.